# SQL SERVER 2008 - SSIS Excel Destination

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel-2007, ssis

I am currently trying to use SSIS to export a large dataset into an Excel destination, however the issue that i have for one of my columns is that records within it exceeds that maximum amount of characters allowed to export. Currently it is set to 255 using Data type  `DT_WSTR`.

To give you a bit of background I had to use the data conversion tool for a few of my source columns to convert from `String [DT_STR]` to `[DT_WSTR]` which partially solved my problem by allowing me to export into excel, except for those records which exceeded the character limit. For now I have just setup a multicast and redirected those records.

Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a memo data type for columns containing more than 255 characters.

[Excel Destination](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137643.aspx)

> Saving memo (ntext) data. Before you can successfully save strings longer than 255 characters to an Excel column, the driver must recognize the data type of the destination column as memo and not string. If the destination table already contains rows of data, then the first few rows that are sampled by the driver must contain at least one instance of a value longer than 255 characters in the memo column. If the destination table is created during package design or at run time, then the CREATE TABLE statement must use LONGTEXT (or one of its synonyms) as the data type of the the memo column.
>
> Memo     Unicode text stream (DT_NTEXT)

Comment: I thought this would be the case, so initially i right clicked on my excel destination, and then clicked on 'show Advanced Editor' I then selected the Input and Output Properties tab and expanded Excel destination Input - External Columns. I select my column and change the data type as suggested but when I run my package it diverts back to its original data type. Is this how you envisage changing it?

Comment: Thanks @DerekKromm for your advice, what are your thoughts based on above?

Comment: That's weird...unfortunately I don't have 2008 installed on this machine to test it out. If this is still open tomorrow I'll take a look on my machine at work

Comment: Oddly enough, I have the same issue with the reverting columns. I did some research and found this on EE: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/MS-SQL-Server/SQL_Server_2008/Q_26926975.html that indicates it may work with Excel 2003 files? Maybe give that a try